# More efficient jQuery for multiple show and hides

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I want to have multiple divs that can be revealed/hidden by slideDown / slideToggle, etc

Currently, the jQuery within the script tags refer to each ID, I'm sure there's is a more efficient way to do this (and to have it so the jQuery within the script tags can serve any about of togglable divs)

http://codepen.io/richerimage/pen/HFqJm

```
<div class="wrap">

<a href="#" id="slick-toggle1" class="text-center reveal">Click to Reveal</a>

<div id="slickbox1" class="reveal-box" style="display: none;">

  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p> 
  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p> 
  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p>  
  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p> 

<span class="slick-hide-holder"><a id="slick-hide1" title="click to close">close &uarr;</a></span>

</div><!-- END of .reveal-box.slickbox1 -->

</div>

<hr />

<div class="wrap">

<a href="#" id="slick-toggle2" class="text-center reveal">Click to Reveal</a>

<div id="slickbox2" class="reveal-box" style="display: none;">

  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p> 
  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p> 
  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p>  
  <p>Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.</p> 

<span class="slick-hide-holder"><a id="slick-hide2" title="click to close">close &uarr;</a></span>

</div><!-- END of .reveal-box.slickbox2 -->

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

        // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
        $('#slickbox1').hide();

        // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link
        $('#slick-hide1').click(function() {
          $('#slickbox1').slideUp('fast');
          return false;
        });

        // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link
         $('#slick-toggle1').click(function() {
          $('#slickbox1').slideToggle(400);
          return false;
        });


  // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
        $('#slickbox2').hide();

        // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link
        $('#slick-hide2').click(function() {
          $('#slickbox2').slideUp('fast');
          return false;
        });

        // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link
         $('#slick-toggle2').click(function() {
          $('#slickbox2').slideToggle(400);
          return false;
        });

});

</script>
```

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ there's a codepen one at the top.

Comment: @megawac the problem comes if there are 50 `slickbox` elements. The jQuery would be repeated 50 times - not very DRY.

Answer (score 1):

With the class structure you have now you can simplify your code to this:

```
$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.reveal-box').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/p8xBt/)

As you can see in the fiddle, the use of classes and traversing within the `wrap` element means this code will work for an unlimited number of `wrap` groups.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link
            $('.slickbox1').click(function(){
                $('#slickbox1').slideToggle(400);
                return false;
            });

            // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link
            $('.slickbox2').click(function(){
                $('#slickbox2').slideToggle(400);
                return false;
            });
        });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <a href="#" class="slickbox1 text-center reveal">Click to Reveal</a>
        <div id="slickbox1" class="reveal-box" style="display: none;">
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <span class="slick-hide-holder"><a id="slick-hide1" class="slickbox1" title="click to close">close &uarr;</a></span>
        </div>
        <!-- END of .reveal-box.slickbox1 -->
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="wrap">
        <a href="#" class="slickbox2 text-center reveal">Click to Reveal</a>
        <div id="slickbox2" class="reveal-box" style="display: none;">
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <p>
                Now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me, now you see me.
            </p>
            <span class="slick-hide-holder"><a id="slick-hide2" class="slickbox2" title="click to close">close &uarr;</a></span>
        </div>
        <!-- END of .reveal-box.slickbox2 -->
    </div>
```